# RavenDB clear database

Tags: c#, ravendb, nosql

How do one clear a RavenDB database of all data must keeping its structure? I have little experience with RavenDB and the NoSQL database so I must ask for assistance. Do I have to create a .NET interface for managing the database or can this operation be performed from the web interface?

```
Raven Studio http://localhost:8080/raven/studio.html
```

If I have understood the structure correctly there are documents that needs to be removed? Can they be removed without damaging the database structure and/or involving .NET integration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A RavenDB database doesn't have a "database structure". All documents in RavenDB are stored as JSON with a metadata element that describes the name of the corresponding CLR type in .NET.

You can just delete all document collections, or you could even recreate the database. The latter would require you to recreate all indexes. All of this can be done from the web interface.

Comment: @anonamas, I'd talk you out of just "_recreate the database_". Check out [this comment from the creator of RavenDb](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ravendb/UmFrmWCO5ms/M83mtg8XDgAJ): "_if you create another db in the same name, you are going to mess it up_". And I did mess it up on v3.5 by recreating the DB